# ¿Cómo encuentro líneas de un CSV en que un campo determinado está en blanco?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script

Tengo el siguiente dataset contenido en `archivo.csv`:

```
name,mass (g),fall,year,reclat,reclon,lat,log
Aachen,21,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330, 50.775000, 6.083330
Aarhus,720,01/01/1951 12:00:00 AM,56.183330,10.233330,,
```

Cómo podeis ver en la segunda linea tiene el campo `lat` y `log` vacíos. Necesito encontrar aquellos campos en los que lat o log son vacíos y mostrar un mensaje que diga missing para toda la línea.

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="archivo.csv"

while IFS=, read -r name mass year reclat reclon lat log
do
    if [[ -z "$lat" || -z "$log"]]
    then
       echo "missing"
    else 
       echo "$lat"
    fi
done < $filename
```

Sin embargo, parece que la condición no es buena o no la está entendiendo bien ya que me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
./Exercici_4d_checkin.sh: línea 9: [[-z: orden no encontrada
./Exercici_4d_checkin.sh: línea 9: -z: orden no encontada 
50.775

./Exercici_4d_checkin.sh: línea 9: [[-z: orden no encontrada
./Exercici_4d_checkin.sh: línea 9: -z: orden no encontada 
56.18333
```

Gracias

Comment: Pega el código en http://shellcheck.net, pues hay distintas cosas de error trivial: `filename="fichero"` (sin espacios), luego la shell es `#!/bin/bash`,  sin espacio antes de /. La condición es `if [[ -z "$lat" || -z "$log" ]]`, sin paréntesis pero con espacios. En cualquier caso, `awk -F, '!$6 || !$7' fichero` ya te mostraría cuáles tienen errores.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' he editado el código según me has dicho y obtengo una nueva salida añadida.

Comment: necesitas añadir espacios alrededor: `if [[ -z "$var" || -z "$otra_var" ]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres filtrar las líneas cuyos ciertos campos estén vacíos, puedes usar Awk de una forma más rápida:

```
awk '!$7 || !$8' fichero
```

Esto imprimirá todas aquellas líneas en las que o bien el 7.º campo o bien el 8.º (o ambos) estén vacíos. Es equivalente a `awk '! ($7 && $8)' fichero`, por lógica preposicional.

Así, si quieres mostrar "missing" cuando no haya nada y la latitud cuando sí la haya, puedes decir:

```
$ awk -F, '!$6 || !$7 {print "missing"; next} {print $7}' fichero
lat
 6.083330
missing
```

Puedes saltar la primera línea añadiendo `NR==1 {next}`.